# Choice of IMODE in gekko optimisation problems

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I'm seeing [here](http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Optimization) that imode=3 is equivalent to the steady-state simulation (which I guess imode=2) except that additional degrees of freedom are allowed.

How do I decide to use imode=3 instead of imode=2?

I'm doing optimization using imode=2 where I'm defining variables calculated by solver to meet constraint using m.Var & other using m.Param. What changes I need to do in variables to use imode=3 ?

Answer (score 3):

Niladri,

IMODE 2 is for steady state problems with multiple data points.

Here is an example:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

xm = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
ym = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.3,0.5,1.0,0.9])

m = GEKKO()

m.x = m.Param(value=np.linspace(-1,6))
m.y = m.Var()
m.options.IMODE=2
m.cspline(m.x,m.y,xm,ym)
m.solve(disp=False)
```

This is a Cubic Spline approximation with multiple data points. When you switch to IMODE 3, it is very similar but it only considers one instance of your model. All of the value properties should only have 1 value such as when you optimize the Cubic spline to find the maximum value.

```
p = GEKKO()
p.x = p.Var(value=1,lb=0,ub=5)
p.y = p.Var()
p.cspline(p.x,p.y,xm,ym)
p.Obj(-p.y)

p.solve(disp=False)
```

Here is additional information on IMODE:

- https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmImode
- https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Modes
- https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/imode.html

Best regards,

John Hedengren

Comment: Thanks for posting this question and answer from the e-mail discussion group.